# htaccess rewrite rule for admin panel

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have the url pattern in my web application like this "**www.mysitename.com/foldername/controller/method**".
And all requested pages are redirected to index.php first on root folder and then it process the requested pages.
but whenever i go to admin panel (**www.mysitename.com/admin**) the url gets the "admin" as a folder name and it shows me the index.php of the admin, (thats normal in this way) then with **controllername** or **methodname** it does not redirect through the index.php of the admin folder.

I want the url in this pattern "**www.mysitename.com/admin/foldername/controller/method**", whenever i visit the "admin". As well as the all 
requested pages through admin should be redirected to the index.php on admin folder first.
here is my htaccess file -

```
    Options -Indexes 
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: So, anything with `/admin/` should go to `/admin/index.php`, and not `/index.php`?

Comment: yes right. anything with `/admin` should go to index.php under admin directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have an `.htaccess` file in your admin directory, or just one in the root directory? You need to have one in each directory.

I just tested this with your `.htaccess` in `/htdocs/pro` and the same `.htaccess` in `/htdocs/pro/admin` and it worked exactly as you explained.

Root htaccess in `/htdocs/pro/.htaccess`

```
Options -Indexes 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Admin htaccess in `/htdocs/pro/admin/.htaccess`

```
Options -Indexes 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Single htaccess file for both in `/htdocs/.htaccess` or `/htdocs/pro/.htaccess`

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# Change '/pro/' if directory is renamed
RewriteBase /pro/

# Change the '/pro/' portion of the condition if directory is renamed 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pro/admin(.+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ admin/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thanks, that works..
but without putting htaccess file into admin directory is there any other thing that could work as same?

Comment: Answer updated with single `.htaccess` covering both admin and root dir to be placed in the root dir. It will check whether there is a match for admin uri first, and if not will assume root uri.

Comment: i was just testing this on my localhost. but it redirecting to  index.php of the localserver. I hv the project in a directory called **pro** in **htdocs**.

Comment: I've updated the `.htaccess` file to work in either `/htdocs/` or `/htdocs/pro/`

Comment: You will just need to update the `/pro/` portion in the .htaccess file on lines 4, 9 and 15 if you rename it to something else.

Comment: anything can i do with `rewritebase` for that?

Comment: Yes, if you store it at directory level you could use `RewriteBase /` and remove references to `/pro/`. If you store it above directory level, you will need `RewriteBase /pro/` and that will need to be changed if you rename the directory.