# htacess redirect all pages to home except admin directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following code my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

I know coding but not good with regex and I didn't play with htaccess file much before. 
I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001934/htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-admin-panel?answertab=active#tab-top) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192044/htaccess-mod-rewrite-reroute-all-urls-to-index-except-admin?answertab=active#tab-top) but however they didn't meet my requirements.

I am using the directory names as permlinks. For example, if user enters `www.mydomaincom/about` a JavaScript code extracts the directory name, compares with the database and polls a page. It also works when the address is written with a trailing slash like `www.mydomaincom/about/`. But there is a problem with this notation.

The wierd thing is, the page is trying to read the html data from index.php which is AOK. But... The elements which need sources like `<img>, <style>, <script>` or style properties which need source directories, are trying to seek for sources from `about/`directory as if it does exist.

I am searching for a htaccess solution which will make `www.mydomaincom/about/`notation behave the same as `www.mydomaincom/about` without affecting the source attributes or properties.

Comment: There is nothing weird about this - this is how resolving relative URLs into absolute ones _works_. Easiest solution: Use URLs that are relative to the web root, starting with a `/` - then it doesn’t matter what the URL of the current document is.

Comment: @CBroe I can't believe it is that easy... Stupid me! But not stupid exactly. I didn't know that a leading `/` means referance to the root directory. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many lines in your code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin
```

These seeingly do the same thing, but they dont.
The first one does "If it does *not* start (`^`) with `/admin`"
The second does "if it is literally *not* `/admin`"

Both are not what you want:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
```

This does "if it does *not* start with `/admin`". This also includes `/admin/`, as that starts with `/admin`

---

Second weird combo is this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
```

The first one is "if it is *not* a file"
The second one you do "if it is *not* a css,js,png,etc"
That last line isn't needed, as the filetypes are files, so you check the same thing twice.

---

Third, you might want to pass the url to your index.php. Shortend and passing it to the index.php looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thans a lot. Good explainations!